# How to pass param in Axios?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

This is the API I am trying to call:

```
https://../api/v1/users/getprofile?access_token={{access_token}}
```

So I would need to pass in access token to call the API above.

Below is how I do it but failed:
client side:

```
return Api().get('getProfile', {params: {accessToken: accessToken}})
```

server side:

```
 request.get(
                "https://../api/v1/users/getProfile?access_token="+ accessToken,
                function (error,response,body){
                    res.send(response.body)
                })
```

console.log shows that the actual URL being called is:

```
https://../api/v1/users/getProfile?access_token=accessToken:eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0aW1lc3RhbXAiOjE1MzM2NDfgfgfgfd
```

How can I fix the error above ?

Answer (score 0):

you should use it (url + querystring)

```
return Api().get('/getProfile?access_token=' + access_token)
```